# What is the purpose of using different app.config for enterprise library?

Tags: .net, wcf, configuration, enterprise-library

I have a business logic which is encapsulated in a library (a project). It has its own app.config with particular settings for Enterprise Library. I was suprised when I find out that a WCF service which uses that library must copy values of app.config of the library.

Once again. If I create Unit tests then I again will create copy of library config

What is the way to deal with it?

Comment: Deal with this by copying the configuration entries to the new location.